# hacer foreach con un model, Asp.NET Core EF

Tags: asp.net, foreach, model

Necesito hacer foreach pero me larga un error

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Mensaje = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

este es el foreach

```
@model UraniaWeb.Models.ViewModels.HomeVM


@foreach (var item in Model.ListaDeArticulos)
{
    <p>@item.TitleArticle</p>
```

en Models/ViewModels/HomeVM.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;


namespace UraniaWeb.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeVM
    {
        public IEnumerable<Article> ListaDeArticulos { get ; set; }
    }
}
```

si falta mostrar algo me dicen, desde ya gracias.